# AJAX call don't call MVC method and returns success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, methods

I'm trying to make AJAX request to a MVC method located in **DefaultController.cs**

```
var booking = { price: price, distance: distance }
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ booking: booking }), //Turns into: "{\"booking\":{\"price\":\"56.1376\",\"distance\":\"35086\"}}"
    url: "/Default/submitBooking",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) { alert("success " + data.d) },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { if (errorThrown != 'abort') debugger; }
})
```

It returns `success undefined`, and no breakpoint in the `submitBooking()` method is hit.

```
public ActionResult submitBooking(Booking booking)
{
   return Json(new { success = true, message = "Booking success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The `Booking` class:

```
public class Booking
{
    decimal price; decimal distance;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }
    public decimal Distance
    {
        get { return distance; }
        set { distance = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this  url: "/Default/submitBooking" is correct url to the action method? do you get any js issues on the browser?

Comment: Check browser console if there is an error listed there.  In Chrome right button click -> Inspect -> Console

Comment: Your return object will be `{ success = true, message = "Booking success" }` which has no `d` property on it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your Action is returning JSON with `success` and `message` properties. Your JS code is then attempting to read a property from the response named `d`, which does not exist, hence the `undefined` value you see.

To fix this you just need to amend your JS code to read the right properties from the response:

```
var booking = { price: price, distance: distance }
$.ajax({
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: { booking: booking }, // no need to JSON.stringify here, jQuery does it for you
  url: "/Default/submitBooking",
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {  
    console.log(data.success);
    console.log(data.message);
  },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    if (errorThrown != 'abort') 
      debugger; 
  }
})
```

Comment: Even with your changes, the method (`submitBooking()`) isn't being hit, i'm thinking this must be related to the Booking class.

Comment: Try sending just `data: booking` instead

Comment: Hi if still your controller action method is didnt reached, then the problem with your url , so try like this  url: '@Url.Action("PostActionName", "ControllerName")',

Comment: I can change the url to whatever i want, it still returns success, and `data` is html.